# jquery catching an autocomplete event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I am getting mad at this...

unfortunately I am to manage a huge legacy app, running jquery 1.4.2 and jquery.ui 1.8...
Managers are not willing to invest into a migration yet - deplorable but understandable, so here I am. This may just generate one more convincing argument to do so...

So I have a text input and I assign the autocomplete.
I need to call a function after a **valid** option has been picked from the list.

I have tried countless combinations...

My latest code:

```
$('#id_city').autocomplete({source: cities, select: my_function});
```

my_function is defined further up as

```
function my_function() {

}
```

but with this one the autocomplete doesn't work at all.
`cities` is an array I build when initializing the page.

If I do

```
$('#id_city').autocomplete(cities)
```

the autocomplete works, but then I can't fire `my_function`

My closest win was to actually bind to the blur event for `#id_city`, but the problem with this is that when a user starts typing and then selects an event with the mouse, the blur event apparently fires too early, giving me the value BEFORE the user actually selected the option with the mouse...

I tried may other approaches:

- on("autocompletechange") as the docs for jquery.ui say, but apparently this can't work as jquery 1.4.2 doesn't support on()...
- $('#id_city').bind("autocompletechange", my_function); here nothing happens...

I also tried with autocompleteselect, no joy.

I scanned the web for many hours and couldn't find anything. Is there a solution to this? I'd be so grateful.

Comment: Have you tried putting `my_function()` in as the select event as an anonymous function?

Comment: I pepared a jsbin here : http://jsbin.com/bozute/1/edit seems to work with your latest code. Can you verify ?

Comment: Working fine here as well: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/akIKz

Comment: Guys, thanks. I can see that it works for you. Will need to continue hunting down what's wrong...:(

Comment: I think I found the beast. Thanks to your code guys! I could see that our (ooooold...) code uses the deprecated 1.2.2 jquery autocomplete plugin for that. So those directives were not working. Opening the plugin, I could see that the event is called "result" there, so registering id_city to that event did the trick! Thank you so much! (NOW I have a strong argument more for suggesting migration...)